Asymptotic analysis of $(\log n)^{\log n}$ vs $n^{\log \log n}$
What is the most informative relationship between the functions
$$\begin{align*}
f(n) &= (\log n) ^ {\log n} \\
g(n) &= n ^ {\log \log n}
\end{align*}$$
out of $f = O(g)$, $f = \Omega (g)$, $f = \Theta(g)$, $f \sim g$, $f = o(g)$ and $f = \omega(g)$?
Between the bases, $n$ grows faster than $\log n$, but between the exponents, $\log n$ grows faster than $\log \log n$. So, it's not immediately obvious to me which function grows faster. I tried evaluating the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ using L'Hopital's rule but that doesn't seem to work.

Have you tried rewriting it with exponentials?

Hint: $a^b = e^{b \log a}$.
